# Google Tag Manager: IF variable value in DOM Ready is "true" then don't fire tag in Window Loaded

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have custom JS variable that returns a boolean, either true or false. In some case this variable may be "true" in DOM Ready and false in "Window Loaded".

I have a bunch of tags firing on Window Loaded and this has to be like that. However, I would like to set up a blocking trigger that blocks these tags from firing, IF the JS variable in DOM Ready is "true", although the same variable in Window Loaded is "false".

Any idea how can I achieve this?
Thanks anyone who can help.
A.

Comment: I am not sure what your issue is here. GTM updates its internal variables every time an event is pushed to the dataLayer, which happens both on DOM ready and Window Loaded, so it is aware that the value of your Boolean has changed. Just add a filter to your Window Loaded trigger, or create an exception trigger with gtm.load as event and your Boolean as filter.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, however I would something like:
IF on gtm.dom {{variable}} === true {
... exception rule here
}